# The image of a measurable set under a measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, fa.functional-analysis

Let $f:X \rightarrow (Y, \mathcal{Y})$ be an abstract function, with $\mathcal{Y}$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. Endow $X$ with $f^{-1}(\mathcal{Y})$. Is then $f(X)$ a measurable set in $Y$? If not, are there simple conditions on $f$ making $f(X)$ measurable? If $\mathcal{Y}$ were a $\sigma$-ring, would this modify anything?

More concisely (and generally): when is the image of a measurable set under a measurable function a measurable set?

Comment: Take $f$ to be the inclusion map of any non-measurable set to get a negative answer for the first question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are actually positive results if you change the context a little bit.
Suppose that $X$ is a separable complete metric space, i.e., a Polish space, 
and assume that $Y$ is something like $\mathbb R^n$, a Polish space that carries
a measure that interacts nicely with the topology like the Lebesgue measure.

Now, if $f:X\to Y$ is Borel measurable, then for every Borel set $B\subseteq X$
the image $f[B]$ is not necessarily Borel in $Y$, but it is Lebesgue measurable in $Y$.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory should contain all the relevant information.  The key word here is "analytic set".  A set is analytic if it is a continuous image of a Borel set in a Polish space.  Since graphs of Borel measurable functions are Borel, the image of a Borel set under a Borel measurable function is analytic, being the projection of a Borel subset of the graph of the function.  And analytic sets are Lebesgue measurable (see the wikipedia entry on analytic sets.)

Comment: I believe the above comment considers only Borel measurable functions $f:V_1\rightarrow V_2$ where $V_1, V_2$ are Polish spaces, so $V_1 \times V_2$ is a Polish space, and the "continuous function" is the projection map $h:V_1\times V_2\rightarrow V_2$ given by $h(v_1,v_2)=v_2$, which can project the graph set $\{(v,f(v)): v \in V_1\}\subseteq V_1 \times V_2$ to the set $f(V_1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathcal{Y}=\left\{\emptyset,Y\right\}$. Every non-surjective function from $f$ on a non-empty set $X$ is measurable, but the image of any non-empty subset is not measurable. Using similar constructions you can get many counterexamples. I would not expect any nice, simple and non-trivial conditions in the case of general $\sigma$-algebras or $\sigma$-rings.